# Nodejs: How to call a function twice with a different parameter?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm creating JSON data and I am having trouble changing the `sub` property of my data.

For my first promise, I want each object's `sub` property to contain the value `theonion`. For the second promise, I want it to be `nottheonion`. However, both files (onion.json and nottheonion.json) end up being identical, both containing data from r/nottheonion

Here is my code.

```
function parse(html, subreddit) {
  var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    $("div#siteTable > div.link").each(function(idx) {
      var title = $(this).find('p.title > a.title').text().trim();
      posts.push({ sub: subreddit, content: title });
    });

  var posts_as_json = JSON.stringify(posts);
  return posts_as_json;
}

var append = file => content => fsp.appendFile(file, content);

rp(onion_url)
  .then(html => parse(html, "onion"))
  .then(append('onion.json'))
  .then(() => console.log('Onion Success'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error: ', err));

rp(not_onion_url)
  .then(html => parse(html, "nottheonion"))
  .then(append('not_onion.json'))
  .then(() => console.log('Not Onion Success'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error: ', err));
```

Comment: where is `posts` declared? You know that both promises share the same `posts`-array?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function parse(html, subreddit) {
  var p = subreddit;
  var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    $("div#siteTable > div.link").each(function(idx) {
      var title = $(this).find('p.title > a.title').text().trim();
      posts.push({ sub: p, content: title });
    });

  var posts_as_json = JSON.stringify(posts);
  return posts_as_json;
}
```

Comment: It works. Not the way I intended, but I realized that I could just have one JSON file with both r/theonion and r/nottheonion in it, which is what that code does. It writes both files with data from both subreddits. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure but var append = file => content => fsp.appendFile(file, content); looks wrong to me..... shouldn't that be var append = (file, content) => fsp.appendFile(file, content); passing it the content from the previous callback